# Modern list item details view and edit form do not show fields for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

Strange behaviour on a SharePoint list in SharePoint Online on a modern team site.
Most users are able to properly use the list. For a very limited set of users the item details view for a list item stopped working.

There were no recent changes in list formatting JSON or permission (in fact it has not been customized at all). I checked the permissions for an affected user. He has "Edit" on the list item an "Read" on the list.

The user can view or edit all fields just fine when using classic experience on the list.

For me the form looks like this
[image]
and for the user like this. Only the sensitivity label an content type are shown.
[image]

The same behaviour occured when opening the item in the single item display form (right click on item, "Copy link" -> use this link as url e.g. https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Lists/MyList/DispForm.aspx?ID=123 )

Interestingly when clicking on "Edit All" in this DispForm.aspx for the user the parameter `loadFormWithNucleus=1` was added to the URL. When manually changing this to `loadFormWithNucleus=0` all fields were shown

Testing this with my not affected user the `loadFormWithNucleus=1` is also added but it does not prevent the fields from loading.

What might be the cause of this? Can I change anything so that the users is again able to see and edit all fields in modern view?

(Also posted this here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/modern-list-item-details-view-and-edit-form-do-not-show-fields/m-p/4011550)